# SUM query in cakephp 3 not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to add the data of same field and want to return a result i used the following query:

```
$total = $this->Details->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('sum(Details.total_downtime+ Details.total_downtime)'), 
    'conditions' => array('Details.site_id' => $id)
));    
print_r($total->toArray());
exit;
```

And I am getting the following result:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => App\Model\Entity\Detail Object ( 
        [displayField] => username 
        [_accessible:protected] => Array ( 
            [*] => 1 
            [id] => 1 
            [site_id] => 1 
            [uptime] => 1 
            [downtime] => 1 
        ) 
        [_properties:protected] => Array ( 
             [sum(Details] => Array ( [total_downtime+ Details] => 4 ) 
        ) 
        [_original:protected] => Array ( ) 
        [_hidden:protected] => Array ( ) 
        [_virtual:protected] => Array ( ) 
        [_className:protected] => App\Model\Entity\Detail [_dirty:protected] => Array ( ) 
        [_new:protected] => 
        [_errors:protected] => Array ( ) 
        [_registryAlias:protected] => Details 
    ) 
)
```

Where can I find my `sum`?

Comment: It gives the double result why ?

Comment: Please use `debug()` instead of `print_r()` it will give you a more appropriate output. Try doing `sum(Details.total_downtime+ Details.total_downtime) as my_sum` and then accessing `$total->toArray()[0]['my_sum']`.

Comment: Did it occur to you that you might have to use a different syntax here than in 2.x? `func()->sum()` etc most likely, see [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are trying to achieve something like this?

```
$query = $Details->find(); 
$query
    ->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('Details.total_downtime')])
    ->where(['Details.site_id' => $id])
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this `collection` object like below:

```
$Details = $this->Details->find();
$Details = $Details->where(['Details.site_id' => $id]);
$sumOftotal_downtime =  $Details->sumOf('Details.total_downtime');
```

[Cookbook Reference](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Details = this->Details->find()->select(['sum'=>'SUM(Details.total_downtime)'])->where(['Details.site_id' => $id])->toArray();
```