# A way to call `->func()->sum()` without having to declare `$query`

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

## What I have

```
$query = $Details->find(); 
$query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('total')]);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34483847/722036)

## What I want

Do everything in one call without having to declare variables I'm not going to use anywhere else.

## What I tried

```
$results = $Details->find('all', [
    'fields' => [
        'sum' => new Cake\ORM\Query()->func()->sum('total'),
    ],
]);
$results = $Details->find('all', [
    'fields' => [
        'sum' => $Details->func()->sum('total'),
    ],
]);
```

Obviously that didn't work, but you get the idea.

The reason why I'm bringing this up is I've seen someone somewhere do exactly that: call `func()` on a shared, already available object. I believed it was the table object, but once I've tried it, it didn't work.

Do you guys think it's possible, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `func()` on a table object, there is no such method, you'd have to obtain a query object, ie `$Table->query()->func()`, and while that will work it's not necessarily the best idea, as it will be a new query object that won't take possible modifications into account that happened on the query object created for your `find()` call.

tl;dr, use a callable, it will receive the current query object as its first argument:

```
$query = $Details
    ->find()
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return [
            'sum' => $query->func()->sum('total')
        ];
    });
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::select()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_select)**